# Incessant pywintypes.com_error in Python when trying to run a macro

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, win32com, vba

All I want to do is open a .xlsm file, run a macro, save the workbook and then quit.  Ideally I could pass the macro as a variable because different situations would run a different macro located in the same workbook.  Here is the code so far.

```
import os, sys
import win32com.client

location = input("AOC or LOC")

macroBook = 'C:/path/to/workbook/solar.xlsm'
macro = 'solar.xlsm!Module1.Tag' + location

try:

    if os.path.exists(macroBook):
        xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=macroBook)
        xl.Application.Run(macro)                 #Getting the error at this line
        xl.Application.Save()
        xl.Application.Quit()
        del xl
except:
    print("Unexpected error:" sys.exc_info()[0])
```

I have finally gotten the macro to run, but I am still getting the same  error once the macro is finished.  This is a lot of headway for me since before I couldn't get the macro to run at all, but this program is useless to me if it just errors out after the macro finishes.

So I'm at a point where I don't even know what to troubleshoot.  The macro runs but I am stuck at the same line that I was when the macro didn't run.  I used to have the 64 bit version and that's what was causing problems but I've switched to 32 bit python.

Could it be getting an error because the macro takes 2-4 minutes to run?  Maybe it isn't waiting for it to finish?  I'm at a loss.  Willing to post my macro as well if needed.

Edit:  I deleted the Application.Save line.  Code now looks like the following.

```
import os, sys
import win32com.client

location = input("AOC or LOC")
taggedData = 'C:/path/to/new/file.csv'
macroBook = 'C:/path/to/workbook/solar.xlsm'
macro = 'solar.xlsm!Module1.Tag' + location

try:

    if os.path.exists(macroBook):
        conn = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
        conn.CommandTimeout = 3600
        xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=macroBook)
        xl.Application.Run(macro)                 #Getting the error at this line
        for sheet in xl1.Worksheets:
            if sheet.Name == "Sheet1":
                nwb = xl.WorkbookAdd()
                sheet.Copy(Before=nwb.Sheet(1))
                nwb.SaveAs(taggedData)
                nwb.Close(True)
        xl.Application.Quit()
        del xl
except:
    print("Unexpected error:" sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Now I am getting a Name Error at `conn.Open()`.  Not sure how that is supposed to get implemented.

Comment: I can't speak to Python, but in VBA there is no `Application.Save` method. `Save` is a `Workbook` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure your COM-interface is timing out. I have encountered similar errors manipulating databases from py / excel... try adding a **command timeout** like this:

```
conn = win32com.client.Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
conn.CommandTimeout = 3600
```

Otherwise, if you are *exclusively* working with Excel / Python, all of your COM-interface and runtime junk is handled smoothly if you use **xlwings** lib. I leave you an example and suggest importing **xlwings.**

*Assuming you have a macro set up like this:*

```
Sub my_macro()
    RunPython ("import my_module; my_module.my_macro()")
End Sub
```

Cook this up in Python:

```
import os
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

def my_macro():
    wb = Workbook.caller()
    Range('A1').value = 1
    # Now basically add whatever you want right here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Expects the Excel file next to this source file, adjust accordingly.
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'myfile.xlsm'))
    Workbook.set_mock_caller(path)
    my_macro()
```

Using the cource code structure above, put whatever you'd like into `my_macro():`

Otherwise, documentation is here, and it is easy: http://xlwings.org/ .

Comment: So I am fairly new to coding.  Could you give a little more info on the command timeout?  Where should that get put in?  Do I leave that as `connection_string`?  If not, what would I put there?

Comment: ADO = ActiveX Data Object.  **CommandTimeout** Sets/returns the maximum number of seconds to wait for a command to complete. This value will be inherited by other ADO components that use this connection object, unless they override their value explicitly. Chances are, your Python is running so fast, the molasses VBA workbook is still opening when it attempts the next line - running the macro. Also, @Rory is correct - fix your application.save() method per his comment.

Comment: Ok, so I understand the purpose and it sounds like what I need.  But what goes in as the connection_string?  I am getting a Name Error by just leaving it as is.